# Реализация отображения имени скрипта в браузере без расширения

Tags: php, .htaccess

Собственно, как реализовать? Т.е. в браузере как при создании данного сообщения, я вижу в адресной строке `http://hashcode.ru/questions/ask/` без указания каких-то пхп файлов или иных расширений вместо допустим `http://hashcode.ru/questions/ask.php` или примером будет служить ваш личный профиль вконтакте, где ваша страница имеет вид `http://адрес/вашид`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и сказал yozh, реализуется это посредством файла .htaccess.

Чтобы дать возможность вызова страниц без указания расширения файла (в данном случае php), создайте файл .htaccess с таким содержанием:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

В случае с PHP и Apache для этого используется mod_rewrite - модуль апача для маппинга URL на пути в локальной системе. Конфигурирование обычно происходит через файл .htaccess. Почитать про это можно, например, [здесь](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/rewriteguide.html).

Comment: Особо ничего не понял

Comment: Этот модуль преобразует путь из одного вида (который виден снаружи) типа nya.ru/somepage в некий внутренний c обычным гет-запросом к конкретному скрипту: nya.ru/page.php?id=somepage. Преобразование задаётся путём различных регулярок и команд - описано по ссылке всё это.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предпочел что-то вроде этого:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Все зависит от задачи ...